# Как ответить на POST-запрос в Golang?

Tags: golang, post, request

У меня  есть код сервера,который получает POST-запрос, сокращает ссылку через clck.ru и печатает его.

```go
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func cutHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("<h1>cut link</h1><h2>POST; applicaton/x-www-form-urlencoded; url:[url]"))
    r.ParseForm()
    pars:=r.Form
    resp,err:=http.Get("https://clck.ru/--?url="+pars.Get("url"))
    if err!=nil{
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    result,err:=ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err!=nil{
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    log.Println(string(result))
}

func main() {
    port:="765"
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/cut", cutHandler)
    log.Println("Server is working")
    http.ListenAndServe(":"+port,mux)
}
```

Как можно изменить код, чтобы он отвечал через POST сокращённой ссылкой в ответ на запрос (т.е. передавал вместе с текстом)?

Comment: не понимаю что значит отвечал на запросы сокращённой ссылкой сразу же ?

Comment: вам же нужно [url] заменить на нужный из ответа, верно?

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы сокращённая ссылка отправлялась вместе со страницей обратно

Comment: я ответил на вопрос ваш, там как раз ответная ссылка отправляется дерните `http://localhost:765/cut?url=https://www.google.com/`

Comment: Вы немного не так ответили. В w.write просто инфа для людей, которые не отправляли post-запрос, о методе api. Url:[url] это параметры, которые должны были отправлятся. Спасибо за ответ, взял оттуда хорошие практики, но там не совсем то написано :)

Comment: я не понимаю. в вопрос ваш добавьте какой запрос юзер должен отправить и какой получить

Comment: На сервер клиент отправляет с помощью Post-запроса ссылку, сервер её сокращает, после чего уже сокращённую ссылку отправляют обратно клиенту

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, извините. Я тут понял неадекатность вопроса. Удалять не буду на случай, если кто-либо тоже задастся таким вопросом :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт, т.к. я не совсем адекватно понял.
Сейчас я понял, что легче отправлять всё нужное в headers, чем Post.

Если что, вот моё решение:

```go
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func cutHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("content-type","applicaton/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    r.ParseForm()
    pars:=r.Form
    resp,err:=http.Get("https://clck.ru/--?url="+pars.Get("url"))
    if err!=nil{
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    result,err:=ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err!=nil{
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    w.Header().Add("Url", string(result))
    
    log.Println(string(result))

    w.Write([]byte("<h1>Autos: /cut</h1><h2>POST; applicaton/x-www-form-urlencoded; url:[url]</h2>"))
}

func main() {
    port:="765"
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/cut", cutHandler)
    log.Println("Server is working")
    http.ListenAndServe(":"+port,mux)
}
```

Спасибо за понимание.

Answer (score 0):

если приложение запаникует(log.Panicln), то оно остановиться. Это не очень хорошо. Сервис должен продолжать работать и обслуживать других пользователей. Поэтому я поменял ответ, если возникла ошибка.

```
func cutHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    formValue := r.FormValue("url")
    resp, err := http.Get("https://clck.ru/--?url=" + formValue)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        w.Write([]byte("error getting the response"))
        return
    }
    result, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        w.Write([]byte("error reading the response"))
        return
    }
    log.Println(string(result))

    w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("<h1>cut link</h1><h2>POST; applicaton/x-www-form-urlencoded; url: %s </h2>", string(result))))
}
```